# Divs floating in tabular way inside another Div

Tags: css, html, css-float

Good morning,
I've been trying to make some divs float inside a bigger div in a tabular way, I would like divs to float from top to bottom and then from left to right (please see the image), is this achievable with CSS only?
[image]

I am currently using float:left for the inner divs.

One more thing, Divs float because the page might grow depending on the screen size.

Thank you!

Comment: Homework or job interview test? Tell us what have you tried so far.

Comment: You can cheat and use a browser that supports CSS3 columns...

Comment: adding on to @MelanciaUK comment, some code would help. :)

Comment: It may be possible with CSS columns (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp) but not ideal due to browser support. What does your HTML look like? Maybe there's another option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using CSS3 Columns. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2aAS9/4/) demonstrating it. The CSS is actually quite simple:

```
.col-4-div {
columns: 10px 4;
-webkit-column-count: 4;
-webkit-column-gap: 10px;
-moz-column-count: 4;
-moz-column-gap: 10px;
}
```

Note there are declarations here to satisfy IE10, Webkit and Firefox browsers. Unfortunately earlier versions of IE do not support this.

Comment: Thank you Holf, I guess that will make the trick. Just to go a bit further, is it possible to get that kind of results but having a dynamic number of columns? I mean the divs will float following the tabular pattern but without specifying the amount of columns?

Comment: Sure, if you specify only the width of the columns, then the number of columns will depend on how wide the window is. See [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/#cw).